# Why does my AND cmos gate have less dissipation than my NAND gate?

Tags: cmos, vlsi

I've just started taking a course in VLSI and from the little I know, this result seems a bit off. Below you can see the layout for the AND and NAND gate I designed :

[image]
[image]

They both seem to be working fine with rise and fall delays less than 0.5 ns. 
( I will add the diagrams if necessary ) . 
Measuring dissipation at the output node of each gate while changing the capacitance of the node I get the following results :

**AND**

[image]

**NAND**

[image]

I would expect the AND gate to have more dissipation but that is not the case here. I even checked the inverter's dissipation which reaches more than 2mWatts. Therefore, adding the inverter in series with the NAND gate should increase dissipation.

What am I missing?

Edit: The capacitance in the pictures is in femtofarads. The capacitance is added to the output of each gate, so it is added to the "out" node in the first picture ( AND gate ) and to the "out21" node in the second picture ( NAND gate ).
In both measurements the gates have the same exact inputs (clock pulses) and dissipation is measured at the output nodes. 
The AND gate has a rise delay of 700 ps and a fall delay of 330 ps.

Edit2: During the measurements I made sure that the two NAND gates are identical.

Comment: You are missing a lot of information. Which node exactly gets the added capacitance? What are the units of capacitance? How does the output rise/fall change between the two gates? How exactly is power measured? How are the inputs changed during the simulation, including their rise/fall times?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I tried to include everything you mentioned in my last edit. In case these are not enough I will upload a full picture of each gate's response soon. All the simulations and measurements are done by the software I use.

Comment: Are the gate widths/lengths all the same?

Comment: I've pasted the same NAND gate in making the AND gate when taking the measurements. So yes, they are identical. Do I maybe need to measure dissipation at the input of the inverter? And then sum these values with those at the output? The sum is indeed bigger and it makes more sense.

Comment: Are you trying to measure the current used by these gates? You should be measuring the current from the VDD supply, but you mentioned "dissipation is measured at the output nodes". Am I missing something?

Comment: @Justin I just want to compare the dissipation of NAND gate with the dissipation of AND gate. Is it wrong measuring dissipation at the output nodes?

Comment: Much of the power in a logic gate does not go through the output node (at least in the case when the output capacitance is low). I would focus on the cap=0 case first. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by measuring dissipation; usually in a simulator you measure voltage or current. If you are measuring current from the output of your circuit, that is not everything; more is being drawn from the supply to charge and discharge all of the intermediate nodes. You should measure current coming from your VDD voltage source (assuming the simulations are done separately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like schematics so you're comparing:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvV07d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And you expect that the left circuit with NAND1 would consume less power than the right NAND2 + INV circuit.

If you assume that the complexity of the circuit is the only factor in determining the power consumption then you would likely be correct.

But more is / could be happening!

- The power dissipation is related to charging the capacitor. In the
  NAND1 circuit there are 2 PMOS in parallel that can charge the
  capacitor.

  In the NAND2 + INV circuit it is the **single** PMOS in the inverter
  charging the capacitor.

  When those 2 PMOS in NAND1 are both switched on, the capacitor is
  charged more quickly **but** that could require a bit more power.
- Are the Width and length of all PMOS the same? To me it looks like they might be different, that can also affect how fast the capacitor is charged.

If you really need to know what is going on then this is best understood when using an Analog circuit simulator like LTSpice. That might be taking this too far though.

Comment: I uploaded the wrong picture for the NAND gate I used in the measurements. The NANDs I used (NAND1 and NAND2) for the measurements are identical. Sorry for that. Also, I think I'm measuring the dissipation only at the output of the inverter. Do I have to add the dissipation at the output of NAND2 to get my total losses?

Comment: *Do I have to add the dissipation at the output of NAND2 to get my total losses?* For a fair total, yes you should. But since the output of NAND2 is only loaded by the inverter, its contribution will be small. So for the high value load capacitor, there will be little difference between the circuits as the load on the output will dominate.

Comment: Should "_When those 2 PMOS in NAND2 are both switched on_" be "_...NAND1..."?

Comment: @TripeHound Well spotted ! I'll correct that.